# Removing spaces out of a line after so many spaces has occured

Tags: mysql, bash, awk, sed

So I am trying to do some tomcat access log analysis by getting it loaded into mysql.  I have the majority of it working, but the last entry in the combined access log is kinda a pain,  it does not always have the same spaces, and the file is space delimited.  I need the last string in the file to either have the spaces removed or replaced with a comma or some other place holder.

I process the file through sed to remove all of the " from the file, so if i can add more to my sed command to do this that would be great,  if i need to run it against something else after the sed command that will work to.

Here is the file before the sed command

```html
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] "GET /irep/client/Cart/Controller/TempController.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "webpage" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4"
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] "GET /irep/client/Libraries/jquery.mobile.datebox.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "webpage" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4"
```

Here is the sed command

```
sed 's/\"//g' filename > newfilename
```

Here is an example string from the file after that command is ran against it.  Since it is space delimited in mysql it tries to make several more columns and it cannot.  so if i can get all the spaces out of the last section that would be awesome.

```html
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] GET /irep/client/Content/css/jquery.mobile.datebox.css HTTP/1.1 304 - webaddress Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] GET /irep/client/Libraries/Bookmark.js HTTP/1.1 304 - webaddress Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4
```

Example of a string where Mozilla is not present.

```
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:21 -0600] GET /irep/images/integra.png HTTP/1.1 304 - - MobileSafari/600.1.4 CFNetwork/711.1.16 Darwin/14.0.0
```

Here is my expected output, sorry had several distractions this morning to this project.

```
IPAddress, ClientUsername, AuthUserName, DateTime, Request/File, Protocol, Status, SizeBytes, Referance address, UserAgent/Browser
```

I would post a screen shot of the table in mysql workbench but i am not allowed to yet.

Basically everything from "Mozilla" to the end of the row i want the spaces replaced or gone, i think a comma or : place holder would be ideal.  Any suggestions?

Ed, here is the error I am getting when running it today.

```
awk: irep-istor_access_log.2015-02-10.txt:4: 166.173.58.240 - - [10/Feb/2015:00:04:07 -0600] "GET /istore/js/cart.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7042 "https://istore.salonservicegroup.com/istore/loginpage.jsp" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
awk: irep-istor_access_log.2015-02-10.txt:4:                                ^ syntax error
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You do realize that there are spaces and brackets in the [date time] column? Why aren't you processing this into CSV or some other format that can be more easily imported?

Comment: Added the raw data to the OP

Comment: This will eventually be a collection system.  Our systems all run on linux and this data will end up in a MySQL database.  loading these directly into excel is easier, but for long term robustness and data retention, i would like the data in a database, which makes this a bit more difficult.  The data base will then be used as a datasource for excel, but we will want to look at months of data to discover trends so on and so forth, which is just not veasable when loading directly into a spread sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the part you have left like this:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/Mozilla.*/){ tgt=substr($0,RSTART); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,",",tgt); $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt } 1' file
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] GET /irep/client/Content/css/jquery.mobile.datebox.css HTTP/1.1 304 - webaddress Mozilla/5.0,(iPad;,CPU,OS,8_1_3,like,Mac,OS,X),AppleWebKit/600.1.4,(KHTML,,like,Gecko),Version/8.0,Mobile/12B466,Safari/600.1.4
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] GET /irep/client/Libraries/Bookmark.js HTTP/1.1 304 - webaddress Mozilla/5.0,(iPad;,CPU,OS,8_1_3,like,Mac,OS,X),AppleWebKit/600.1.4,(KHTML,,like,Gecko),Version/8.0,Mobile/12B466,Safari/600.1.4
```

but you should just be using one small, simple, awk script for the whole thing, whatever that is.

I see you just added some pre-sed input (but still no expected output) so:

```
$ cat file
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] "GET /irep/client/Cart/Controller/TempController.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "webpage" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4"
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] "GET /irep/client/Libraries/jquery.mobile.datebox.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "webpage" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4"
$              
$ awk '{gsub(/"/,"")} match($0,/Mozilla.*/){ tgt=substr($0,RSTART); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,",",tgt); $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt } 1' file
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] GET /irep/client/Cart/Controller/TempController.js HTTP/1.1 304 - webpage Mozilla/5.0,(iPad;,CPU,OS,8_1_3,like,Mac,OS,X),AppleWebKit/600.1.4,(KHTML,,like,Gecko),Version/8.0,Mobile/12B466,Safari/600.1.4
24.240.97.38 - - [09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600] GET /irep/client/Libraries/jquery.mobile.datebox.js HTTP/1.1 304 - webpage Mozilla/5.0,(iPad;,CPU,OS,8_1_3,like,Mac,OS,X),AppleWebKit/600.1.4,(KHTML,,like,Gecko),Version/8.0,Mobile/12B466,Safari/600.1.4
```

Different approach: here is how to convert your input file into a CSV file:

```
$ cat tst.awk        
BEGIN{
    OFS=","
    print "ipAddr", "dash1", "dash2", "dateTime", "getCmd", "number", "info", "browser"
}
{
    gsub(OFS,";")

    ip = $1

    dash1 = $2
    dash2 = $3

    match($0,/\[[^]]+\]/)
    dt = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)

    match($0,/"[^"]+"/)
    get = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
    $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)

    num = $1
    dash3 = $2

    match($0,/"[^"]+"/)
    info = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
    $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)

    match($0,/"[^"]+"/)
    browser = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)

    print ip, dash1, dash2, dt, get, num, info, browser
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ipAddr,dash1,dash2,dateTime,getCmd,number,info,browser
24.240.97.38,-,-,09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600,GET /irep/client/Cart/Controller/TempController.js HTTP/1.1,304,webpage,Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML; like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4
24.240.97.38,-,-,09/Feb/2015:07:38:23 -0600,GET /irep/client/Libraries/jquery.mobile.datebox.js HTTP/1.1,304,webpage,Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML; like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4
```

Comment: I am sorry for not showing the expected output.  That script is amazing though, thank you so much for it.  It is almost exactly as it is needed.  I will post what the values i am looking for.  The only issue with the script you just posted is it removed the two - - after the IP address.  those dashes are place holders.  I will post the format in the OP

Comment: So thank you for all the help Ed,  i seem to have an issue today.  When running the same exact thing against the log generated yesterday, i get a syntax error on every line.  I will add it to the OP now

Comment: It's hard to debug a syntax error without seeing the command line that was executed (**HINT!!!**) but my guess is you left off an enclosing tick (`'`) from your awk command if it's on the command line or you are using `awk -f tst.awk -f file` or `awk tst.awk -f file` or something instead of `awk -f tst.awk file` so you're telling awk to execute your data file instead of read it.

Comment: i am doing awk -f tst.awk file > newfile

Comment: No, you aren't, assuming `tst.awk` contains the awk script while `file` contains your data. Your error message is specifically stating that awk is finding a syntax error while executing the contents of `file` and `awk -f tst.awk file` will NOT execute the contents of `file`.